# Installing CERN ROOT in anaconda environment- packages are not available from current channels:

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, root-framework, conda-forge

I am attempting to install CERNS ROOT in anaconda, for use of pyRoot. (I am using conda 4.10.3)

I have set up a new environment with python 2.7, because I believe I read somewhere that ROOT does not work well with python 3. After installing python to the new environment and activating it, I have added conda-forge to the current channels and attempted to install the following:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/root-dependencies

Using:

`conda install -c conda-forge root-dependencies`

This however returned the following:

```
(pyRoot) C:\Users\George>conda install -c conda-forge root-dependencies
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - root-dependencies

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I am not sure why this is not working, as I am fairly sure the root-dependencies are available on the conda-forge channel as per the link.

I have tried the following:

`SET CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1`

Just in case it was part of the free channel that may have been dropped, but I still get the same error.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is not built for **win-64** platform, which is what OP channel configuration indicates is being used. Consider WSL2 or Docker ([ROOT Project provides pre-built images](https://hub.docker.com/u/rootproject)).

If you would like Conda Forge to build a Windows version, [submit an Issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/root-feedstock/issues). Just be aware that ROOT Project itself only has beta support for Windows natively, so it's likely not a trivial task.